# Slickgrid changes the ID from my data and dont clean up the empty row

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, slickgrid

Im trying to update my grid without the need for refreshing! Right now, it updates only the grid, but dont know why, it changes the id to the last one inserted and dont "clean up" the empty row! When I try to insert data, it clears it .
Im kinda new with ajax and slickgrid! I've tried to see the ajax example from slickgrid, but I got some errors!
Do I need to re-upload the onCellChange and so on ? I just wanted to update th grid with the new data.
Any help?

Thanks in advance

So, I've tried re-draw the table re-using my actual drawning code, but im failling to re-draw with correct data.

Function to re-draw grid

```
function desenhaGrid() {
    $("#myGrid").ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/SlickGrid/GetData',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (jsonResult) {
                    for (var key in jsonResult) {
                        if (jsonResult.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            //print table
                            var d = (data[key] = {});
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                d["#"] = i + 1;
                            }
                            d["id"] = jsonResult[key].id;
                            d["t_nome"] = jsonResult[key].t_nome;
                            d["t_prof"] = jsonResult[key].t_prof;
                            d["t_data"] = jsonResult[key].t_data;
                            d["t_morada"] = jsonResult[key].t_morada;
                            d["t_percCompleto"] = jsonResult[key].t_percCompleto;
                        }
                    }


                    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);

                   dataView.beginUpdate();
                   grid.invalidateAllRows();
                   dataView.setItems(data);
                   grid.render();
                   dataView.endUpdate();
                                       }
            });

        });
    });
}
```

and this is my onAddNewRow

```
        grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            var idData = jsonResult[key].id + 1;
            var item = { "id": idData, "t_nome": '', "t_prof": '', "t_data": '', "t_morada": '', "t_percCompleto": '' };
            $.extend(item, args.item);
            dataView.addItem(item);
            //if user press enter
            grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(function (e) {
                var keyPressed = event.keyCode || event.which;
                if (keyPressed == 13) {
                    alert("add");
                    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(item);
                    $.post("/SlickGrid/addGridEnter", $("input[name=mydata]").val(myJSON));
                    console.log(myJSON);
                    desenhaGrid();
                }
            });

        });
```

I expected it to re-draw my grid with all the data. Instead, its changing all the id's to the last one inserted and when I try to insert data in the last row, wont let me (it clears it after I leave the cell).

UPDATE:

I've udpate the function to draw the grid

```
function desenhaGrid() {
    $("#myGrid").load(function () {
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/SlickGrid/GetData',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (jsonResult) {
                    dataView.beginUpdate();
                    grid.invalidateAllRows();
                    dataView.setItems(jsonResult);
                    dataView.endUpdate();
                    grid.render();
                }
            });

        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a SlickGrid issue. There are all kind of problems with the javascript. For example:

- why are you using `$("#myGrid").ready(` ? the `ready` event only fires when the DOM has finished loading
- the entire copy operation from `jsonResult` to `data` just ends up with the same data. why not use `jsonResult` directly?
- the section `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { d["#"] = i + 1; }` 
  runs once for each row added to `data`, it should just run once at the end, outside of the loop
- you are subscribing to the keydown event once for each row added to the grid. you should just subscribe once. listening for an Enter key is also a very poor method of determining if a row has been entered. what if someone clicks on another row before pressing Enter?

Slickgrid is a client-side grid. This means data does not need to be persisted after every change. It's a common approach to use a 'save' button, or detect if the active row has changed.

Comment: Hello Ben!
So, for answering your questions :
1) As stated above, Im kinda new to Ajax ! I just saw some examples and was hoping for the best ! I did change to click or load, but still gettint how to work with it.
2) Im now just wrapping the json to the grid, so the code is a littler more clean ( i wil edit after this ).
3) Yeah, I noticed that as well! that loop is used just to add a number to the row ( more a visual thing)
4) This is just for now ! Im testing and decomposing slickgrid the best I can ! I was thinking about onCellChange (when the user leff the cell, it will save to DB )

Comment: Ben, when you say "you should just subscribe once", can you please elaborate ?! Should I first detect the enter and then change apply the onAddNewRow?
Later, i will try to update IRL (e.g, when the oncellchange is on, apply the change on the DB directly - more or so like an excel).

Comment: Ajax has a tendency to be quite complicated. You need a strategy for validation, for example. How do you know if the row has valid data and can actually be persisted to the data store? Often an 'edit row' and then 'save row' and 'cancel edits' button are used. If there is no validation, then you would be best to just persist the cell value using AJAX using a customised cell editor.  There should be no need to redraw the grid unless the data has been changed by a remote source.

Comment: Note the problem with your desenhaGrid function is that it doesn't actually repopulate the grid data, it just sets that up to happen on the DOM ready event. Which has already happened when the page loaded, so will likely never fire again. Plus you are adding the event again, so if the ready event did ever happen, the event would fire as many times as you called it.

Comment: Hey Ben! Thanks for you answer! Yeah, Ajax is a little tricky but I got it working! 
I was trying to redraw the grid after the user inserts a new row! Its doing it right now! :)
As you said, "Which has already happened when the page loaded, so will likely never fire again"! it never fired the event! Right now is doing it!
Thanks once again!
Btw, if you dont mind : do you know if its possible to use both cellseletionmodel and rowselectionmodel at the same time ? For what Im testing, one overlaps the other!

Comment: not possible to use both. you'd have to create a custom selectionmodel for your purposes.